# Using Glusterfs Dist-Replica Storage Pool for Hyper-V Virtual Machine Storage

Tags: hyper-v, samba, nfs, glusterfs

Am chasing down some information regarding an upcoming project.
So Basically we have a large Glusterfs Dist-Replica Storage pool running on ubuntu and we want to have several virtual machines running off this from our windows 2012 server,

Now we are using Hyper-V to run the Virtual machines and so far I am having a bit of trouble getting the VHDX to actually create on the Gluster Storage pool.

I've created a mount point with Gluster and have tried to share it out with Samba yet it would never create the VHDX or run an existing one on the cluster as it continously would throw errors like: Error Incorrect Function on the hypervisor.
Changed Permissions, Allowed Anon access, Made sure it could RW etc etc still would not allow any VHDX to be created.

Then Tried to share it out with NFS and the Hyper-V when creating a VM would throw out errors like this:
File System limitation
Found out this is rather common:
https://slog.starwindsoftware.com/hyper-v-vms-on-nfs-share/

So I'm curious if anyone out there does have Hyper-V Virtual machines running on Glusterfs and if so how you got it configured?
Any information at all would be fantastic :)

On a side note please let me know if anyone has used VMware with Samba/NFS and if this performed better than Hyper-V.

Thanks team

Answer (score 2):

Hyper-V can do SMB3 and iSCSI while SMB3 is clearly preferred: CSVFS is a joke compared to VMFS5, Microsoft has no scalable clustered file system so has to use network redirector crutches.

VMware can do NFS and iSCSI pretty much same way: proper configuration will saturate network.

P.S. We prefer to use VMware with NFS only because it's easier to configure though.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use file-based storage (a file server of one kind or another), Hyper-V requires that the protocol be SMB 3.0 or later.  NFS isn't supported.

If you can expose an iSCSI LUN from Gluster, that would work, too.